# Generate method that calls class private field method by just forwarding parameters?

Tags: c#, resharper

Is it possible in Visual Studio or ReSharper to generate a method that just forwards parameters to a private field's method?

```
class Inner
{
 public void Test(String a, String b){}
}
class Outer
{
  private Inner _inner;
  public Outer(Inner inner)
  {_inner = inner;}
  /*
  //I want to generate this:
  public void Test(String a, String b)
  {
    _inner.Test(a, b);
  }
  */
}
```

Comment: This feature is called _"Generate delegating members"_ and is described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Generation__Delegating_Members.html)

Comment: @RenéVogt exactly what I need. Make an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Resharper feature you are looking for is called *"Generating delegating members"* and is described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Generation__Delegating_Members.html):

> To generate delegating members
>
> 1. In the editor, set the caret on the type name or within a type at the line where you want to insert delegating members. If the caret is on the type name, the generated code will be added in the beginning of the type declaration.
> 2. Press Alt+Insert or choose ReSharper | Edit | Generate Code… from the main menu. Alternatively, you can press Ctrl+Shift+A, start typing the command name in the pop-up, and then choose it there.
> 3. In the Generate pop-up menu, select Delegating Members.
> 4. In the Generate dialog that appears, you will see a list of private properties and fields in the current type. You can expand these items to see the members of their types. Select some or all of these type members, and ReSharper will generate wrappers in the current type that delegate execution to selected type members.
> 5. Click Finish to complete the wizard.
>      You can also click Options to review or modify common code generation preferences on the Code Editing | Members Generation page of ReSharper options.